# Azure DevOps Trigger Pipeline Whenever a Tag is added to any Repository in Product

Tags: azure-devops

Does anyone know of a way to trigger a pipeline based off of any tag being added to any repo inside of a project.  My goal is to dynamically create a new build pipeline whenever a developer adds a specific tag to their repo.

Example:

projectName/RepoA
Tag: TestTag (Start Pipeline)

projectName/RepoB
Tag: TestTag  (Start Pipeline)

projectName/RepoC

...

projectName/RepoZ
Tag: TestTag  (Start Pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using classic pipeline. You can enable the CI trigger and set the tags triggers like `refs/tags/Test*` in the branch filter. See below:

[image]

If you are using yaml pipeline. You can set the tag triggers in the trigger section.See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#triggers).

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include: 
    - Test*
```